# Use of quotes within get function (get())

Tags: r

I hope to get some help on the use of quotation marks within a string for get().

Say, I want to retrieve an element from a list

```
some_list <- list(element1=11,element2=22,element3=33)
```

naturally, I can simply reference this element through

```
some_list[['element1']]
```

However, once I use this as a string within get(), R throws this error message

```
get("some_list[['element1']]")

> Error in get("some_list[['element1']]") : 
  object 'some_list[['element1']]' not found
```

I cannot figure out why this is the case. get() works fine when used with strings that do not have quotation marks within them, e.g.

```
get("some_list")
```

I also tried escaping the quotation marks within the string (although I don't this I would need to since they are single quotation marks) but it does not work either.

```
some_list[["\'"element1"\'"]]
```

What am I missing.

Comment: And really, you probably shouldn't be using `get` at all. That's a sign that you're probably not doing something in an R-like way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get` won't do that.

`some_list[['element1']]` isn't the name of an object in an R environment (in a technical sense). When you type `some_list[['element1']]` at the console, R parses the expression, looks up the symbol `some_list` and then calls the function `[[`. `get` is intended just for the symbol lookup piece of that.

(Technically, my sequence of events there probably isn't right, but I listed them that way to help make the issue clear. Really, R is just parsing the expression, and then calling `[[` with *arguments* `some_list` and `'element1'`, and those symbols are subsequently looked up.)

Comment: Excellent explanation, I wasn't aware that [[ is a function. Completely barked up the wrong tree by suspecting quotation marks to be the culprit. Thanks

Comment: @SprengMeister (Almost) everything in R is a function call! :)

Comment: To avoid questions like this in the future, @joran, do you have a recommendation what kind of publication/manual etc, explain such details?

Comment: @SprengMeister Hadley is writing a book (due out soon) that is almost entirely available [online](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/). It's very good, and delves into lots of the more "tricky" aspects of R. The [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) is also an excellent reference for "gotchas".

Answer (score 1):

The quotes have nothing to do with it. Run:
    `get("some_list")[['element1']]`